# Is there a way to generate Amazon transparency label via API?

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I didn't find any useful information on this topic on Amazon site, I would believe the answer is NO, but still want to try it here.

We managed some brands which have brand registry and also enrolled Amazon transparency service, means that we will need to generate the unique transparency QRCode labels and put them onto each products before shipping them.

It is currently a little bit manual:

- One of my colleague will login to Amazon transparency website, creates labels there.
- Rename the label PDFs with SKU names.
- Login to our web app, and upload the PDF files.

It would be really nice if the web app itself can generate these labels via an API.